# Solving $\frac{\log(x)}{x}=c$, where $c < e^{-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am just wondering if there is an easy way to solve

$$\frac{\log(x)}{x}=c, \text{where } x > 1 \text{ and } c < e^{-1}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. The solution is
$$x=-\frac{W(-c)}{c},$$
where $W$ is the [*Lambert W function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), and in the solution $W$ means both $W_0$ and $W_{-1}$.

To give more details.

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\log\left(-\frac{W(-c)}{c}\right)}{-\frac{W(-c)}{c}} & = c \\
\log(-W(-c))-\log c & = -W(-c) \\
\log(-W(-c))+W(-c) & = \log c \\
W(-c)e^{W(-c)} & = -c,
\end{align}
$$
and this satisfies the definition of Lambert W function.

Comment: Then the remaining question is: Is this easy? I.e., is the answer to the OP “yes” or “no”? I suppose that depends on perspective …

Comment: Two solutions possible, I think. Check sign changes at $x=1, \infty$.

Comment: @Macavity Right! Do you know how to find the other solution?

Comment: The second real soln is $-W_{-1}(-c)/c$, on the other side of $e$.

Comment: @Macavity Thanks! Does it matter if I use $W_{-1}(c)/c$ or $W_{-1}(-c)/-c$ for the second answer?

Comment: Yes, it does. Since $W_{-1}(c)/c \neq -W_{-1}(-c)/c$.