# Solving $\frac{\log(x)+c_1}{x}=c_2$, where $c_2 < e^{-1}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

There is an answer when $c_1=0$ at ([Solving $\frac{\log(x)}{x}=c$, where $c < e^{-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919670/solving-frac-logxx-c-where-c-e-1)).
How could we solve the following?

$$\frac{\log(x)+c_1}{x}=c_2, \text{where } x > 1,~c_1>0, ~\text{and}~ c_2 < e^{-1}$$

Comment: You can have a solution in terms of [Lambert W function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217254/apparently-cannot-be-solved-using-logarithms/217262#217262).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal It makes sense to have such a solution, but could you explain it more?

Comment: Have you give it a try?

Comment: See the answer.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Thanks!

Comment: Gimili : You are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Related problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217254/apparently-cannot-be-solved-using-logarithms/217262#217262). Here is how. Make the change of variables $\ln(x)=u$

> $$ \frac{\log(x)+c_1}{x}=c_2  \implies  (u+c_1){e^{-u}}=c_2 . $$

Another change of variables $  u+c_1 = z $ gives

> $$ ze^{-z}= c_2e^{-c_1} $$

Replace $z=-y$ gives

> $$ ye^y=-c_2e^{-c_1} \implies y = W(-c_2e^{-c_1}), $$

where $W(x)$ is the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Now you need to go backward with your substitutions. The final answer should be

> $$ x =e^{-c_1}\, e^{-W(-c_2e^{-c_1})} $$

Comment: There is a typo, which is missing the negative sign for $c_1$ before the final answer $$ ye^y=-c_2e^{-c_1} \implies y = W(-c_2e^{-c_1}) $$

Comment: @ElrondGimli: Ok. I'll fix that. Thanks for the comment.